# Lucene.net search and underscore

Tags: lucene.net

The Underscore '_' works like an AND, doesn't it?

When searching for any of

```
test_12 , 12_test , 12 AND test , test AND 12
```

I get the same hit.

But why is there a problem with the wildcard?

```
mytest* AND abc_IN_CRM_C  --> finds results!
abc_IN_CRM_C_mytest* --> no results!
abc_IN_CRM_C AND mytest* --> results ?!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the StandardAnalyzer, then the text is split on underscores. That's why you get the same results as using "AND".

Also see [Lucene search and underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520479/lucene-search-and-underscores)

Comment: what does split mean? really two words? than should be the last to querys be equal, don't they? but why are the results different?

Comment: I don't have a lucene install at hand, but it might be that it tokenizes it differently with the wildcard.